# How to find duplicates in pandas dataframe and print them

Tags: python, pandas

I am checking a panadas dataframe for duplicate rows using the `duplicated` function, which works well. But how do I print out the row contents of only the items that are true?

for example, If I run:

```
duplicateCheck = dataSet.duplicated(subset=['Name', 'Date',], keep=False)
print(duplicateCheck)
```

it outputs:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
for row in duplicateCheck.keys():
    if row == True:
        print (row, duplicateCheck[row])
```

Which prints the items from the dataframe that are duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not

```
duplicateCheck = dataSet.duplicated(subset=['Name', 'Date',], keep=False)

print(dataSet[duplicateCheck])
```